# In clojure can you apply a function to all elements in a collection and have the return value be the input for the next?

Tags: function, collections, clojure

Say you have a collection like this `({A: 1 B: 2} {A: 2 B: 5} {A: 4 B: 7})` with an unspecified amount of {A: B:} parts and a function `(func arg1 arg2)`.

If we assume there is some initial state `state` and that every call to `func` generates a `new-state`.
Is it possible to construct something that acts like this?

```
(->(func state {A: 1 B: 2})
(func {A: 2 B: 5}) 
(func {A: 4 B: 7}))
```

Basically the first argument is the new state and the second is the next `{A: B:}` from the collection.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As a side note, `{:a 1 :b 2}` would be more commonly seen in Clojure. I.e., using keywords for the keys of a map. Though, `{A: 1 B: 2}` is syntactical legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this function is called [`reduce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce):

```
(reduce
  func
  initial-state
  input-sequence)
```

or a version where the first element of the input sequence is used as initial state (check the function doc to see the details of its behaviour):

```
(reduce 
  func
  input-sequence)
```

For example:

```
(reduce
  +
  100
  [1 2 3 4 5])
;; => 115

(reduce
  +
  [1 2 3 4 5])
;; => 15
```